# NestJS - Grpc client: RpcException from server is serialized to an Error instead of RpcException

Tags: nestjs, grpc-node

I've been at this all day and can't seem to find a solution,
please help :)

The service communication works, the issue is with the error handling...

#### Scenario:

**Service-A** is invoked via HTTP. (probably not relevant but just in case)
**Service-A** calls **Service-B** via RPC.
**Service-B** throws an error.
an exception filter on **Service-B**'s controller catches that error and translates it to a `RpcException` and returns that to to **Service-A**.
**Service-A** receives an `Error` not a `RpcExcpetion`.

The error is caught in the global error handler as it is not recognized as a `RpcException`
(would have been caught in **Service-B**'s `RpcExceptionFilter`...)

#### Some code:

##### **Service-A**:

###### client configuration

```
    @Module({
        imports: [...],
        controllers: [...],
        providers: [{
            provide: 'somePackage',
            useFactory(configService: ConfigService) {
                return ClientProxyFactory.create(
                    {
                        transport: Transport.GRPC,
                        options: {
                            url: 'localhost:5000',
                            package: 'somePackage',
                            protoPath: 'pathToProto',
                        },
                    }
                );
            },
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }]
    })
```

###### client service injection and init

```
    export class ServiceA implements OnModuleInit {
    
        private someService: SomeServiceClient;
    
        onModuleInit(): any {
            this.someService = this.client.getService<SomeServiceClient>('SomeService');
        }
    
        constructor(@Inject(somePackage) private client: ClientGrpc)
    }
```

###### client method call

`await lastValueFrom(this.someService.workWork(workWorkRequest));`

##### **Service-B**:

###### error conversion (ExceptionFilter)

```
catch(exception: RpcException){
        const rpcException: RpcException = someConversionFunction(exception);
        return throwError(() => rpcException.getError());
    }
```

##### **some logging outputs**:

this is what thrown on **service-a**:
`[error][2022-05-30T18:58:13.132Z]-[App/Main] - 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: Some Service-B error message`
if i try catch the call and log the error:

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: Some Service-B error message
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:81:24)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:343:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:462:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:424:48)
    at @grpc/grpc-js/src/call-stream.ts:323:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
    code: 9,
    details: 'Some Service-B error message',
    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}
```

what i expect is basically the same, just as a RpcError:
`RpcException [Error]: Some Service-B error message`

I've tried to minimize the code as much as possible...
Any input is welcome...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this,
It is now possible to add an error serializer when creating the ClientProxy like so:

```js
class ErrorHandlingProxy extends ClientGrpcProxy {
  serializeError(err) {
    return new RpcException(err);
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'HERO_PACKAGE',
      useFactory() {
        return new ErrorHandlingProxy(grpcClientOptions.options);
      },
    },
  ],
  controllers: [HeroController],
})
export class HeroModule {}
```

More details in [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/10104)